# Is there an efficient way to include SCSS mixin into partials when @use/@forward?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm kind of new to SCSS and I wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way to include mixins into my partials without having to reference it every time. For example, at the top of every partial where I use the mixin for media queries this is what I have:

```
@use '../abstracts/mixins' as *;

.wrapper {
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding-inline: 1.5rem;

    @include breakpoint(medium) {
        max-width: 80rem;
    }
}
```

So, I wanted to know if there was a better way to do this without having to repeat the @use every time? Or is doing this in each partial that I want to use this mixin in fine?

Comment: Are you using `sass-loader`?

Comment: That is the proper way of doing it. Using "Use" has no load impact on the final CSS. However, I would put mixins, variable and config files in a different directory as partials. Create an index scss file and forward all of them into the final CSS

Comment: @Arkellys No, I am using VS code extension.

Comment: @Brad Hi brad, thanks for the suggestion. I created a helpers partial and did as you mentioned (forwarded the mixins into it then included the helpers in the main file). One more question, now I get an error that the mixin is undefined, does that mean that now where ever I want to use the mixin I have to reference as (@use '../abstracts/helpers' as *; ) in whatever partial I want to use it in? Sorry, for all the questions

Comment: Inside your abstract folder, create an index.scss file.  In the index file, type "@forward "helpers"; Helpers being the partial. In the rest of your sass files use '../abstracts' as *.  In your main scss file that gets translated to CSS, type @use "abstracts";  I use the SMACSS methods with a seperate directory for modules, base files layouts and themes. Wach one has an index file, and each one is referencxed in the main.scss file

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your time and sharing your knowledge, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure. I love using SASS